# Create User Defined Contact Field in Outlook using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, contacts, user-defined-fields

I am trying to write an outlook Macro that will create a new field on all Contacts and then populate that field based on another already existing field. Here's what I have so far. It doesn't seem to create anything.

```
Sub ChangeField()
    Dim ContactsFolder As Folder
    Dim Contact As ContactItem
    Dim objProperty As UserDefinedProperty

    Set ContactsFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
    MsgBox ("Contacts Found: " & ContactsFolder.Items.Count)

    With ContactsFolder.UserDefinedProperties
        Set objProperty = .Add("CustomCompanyField", olText)
    End With

    For Each Contact In ContactsFolder.Items
        Contact.CustomCompanyField = Contact.CompanyName
        Contact.Save
    Next    
End Sub
```

Can this be done through VBA? Or can contact fields only be created manually? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace the line

```
 Contact.CustomCompanyField = Contact.CompanyName
```

with

```
 Contact.UserProperties.Add("CustomCompanyField", olText).Value = Contact.CompanyName
```